# Finding present root directory in multiple modules in maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have application like d:\devbox\student-test (is the main app) which contain 3 modules like selenium-test, webapp, server-side (these 3 are modules).
Under "selenium-test module" I have src, 
In src -- main and test

In main - have java, then packages contains selenium code.

In test - have java and resources
          java contains test code
          resources contains some files, etc.

I have to read files under java which is in resources file.

I have defined file like File f = new File ("src/test/resources/some.txt");

When I call f.getAbsolutePath(), its giving wrong file path, the file path like below.
"d:\devbox\student-test\src\test\resources\some.txt"
Actually its ignoring the sub module called "selenium-test".

Could you guys help me to fix.. thank you very much

Comment: Can write down a sketch of your folder structure and where your modules are located cause based on what your wrote it's not clear.

Comment: I used this.getclassLoader().getResource(".").getpath(), and it worked. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this.getclassLoader().getResource(".").getpath(), and it worked. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Better use things like this to locate your resources

```java
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/some.txt");
```